# VSCode Black Menu Bar

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

So in the last update's Release Notes (1.27.2) I saw this screenshot:

[image]

But my menubar looks as ugly as usual. How can I enable the black menubar (which I assume is implemented as part of the HTML page rather than a native Windows menubar)?

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is not very obvious, in the settings:

> // Adjust the appearance of the window title bar. Changes require a
>   full restart to apply.

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
```

And then you will need to choose a dark theme that actually provides that color:

> // Specifies the color theme used in the workbench.

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
```

Or you can change the titleBar's colors in the `colorCustomizations`:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "titleBar.activeBackground": "#555",      
      "titleBar.activeForeground": "#fff"
  }
```

So either choose a theme that sets the titleBar's colors or change it yourself with these last two colorCustomization settings.  But in either case this must be set:

`"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",`

Comment: This part was key for me to see the menu/title bar changes: _Changes require a full restart to apply_

Comment: if you have installed vscode from ```flatpak```, this solution fix your problem.